# How effeciently count categories (250) of a categorical attribute? PostgreSQL or Python

Tags: postgresql, count, categorical-data

I have a big database with 50 attributes (8 categorical) and I need to create a summary with a count of all categories of each variable grouped by city and state. One of the attributes has over 250 categories.

So far I was able to create a query that counts one category per attribute at the time grouped by city and exported to csv.

```
(select city as "City", COUNT(use4) as "use2056"
from demo
where use4 = '2056'
group by city
order by city asc)
```

I was thinking about manually copying and pasting (I know it will take forever) but I get outputs with different rows. Also, there are cities with the US with the same name (I will eventually need to visualize it). I tried to use several SELECT per query but I cannot make it work.

```
Select
(select city as "City", COUNT(use4) as "use2056"
from demo
where use4 = '2056'
group by city
order by city asc),
(COUNT(use4) as "use2436"
from demo
where use4 = '2436'
group by city
order by city asc),
(COUNT(use4) as "use9133"
from demo
where use4 = '9133'
group by city
order by city asc)
```

I also tried to add the city and county and additional counts

```
(select zip as "ZIPCODE", city, county, COUNT(use4) as "Use4count1466", COUNT(use4) as "Use4count9133"
from demo
where use4 = '1466',
where use4 = '9133' 
group by zip, city, county
order by zip asc)
```

is there anyway to do this efficiently? create a loop that keeps counting every category of each attribute? How many SELECT can you have in a query? I need to find a way to display zipcode, county, city and count all the categories of each categorical attribute.

Comment: Your data model is seriously broken; you need to normalize your data. At a minimum you need tables for attributes, categories, city and perhaps state and zip_codes.  (Contrary to popular belief US zip code is a M:M to both city and state._

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it. I am relatively new. I am sure you can tell by the question. Any specific tip on how to approach the task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use filtered aggregation to do this in a single query:

```
select city, 
       count(*) filter (where use4 = '2056') as use2056,
       count(*) filter (where use4 = '2436') as use2436,
       count(*) filter (where use4 = '9133') as use9133,
from demo
where use4 in ('2056', '2436', '9133')
group by city;
```

You can apply the same for the second query:

```
select zip as "ZIPCODE", 
       city, 
       county, 
       count(*) filter (where use4 = '1466') as use4count1466, 
       count(*) filter (where use4 = '9133') as use4count9133
from demo
where use4 in ('1466','9133')
group by zip, city, county
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! This is very helpful.